# I want to Show Static HTML files from Assets folder into Webview in Custom Dialog

Tags: android

I am trying to show a html file from assets folder into a Custom Dialog Box. But getting Errors. 
I am using following Codes.

My Custom Dialog Class

```
public class RobozoxDialog extends Activity{
Dialog my;
public RobozoxDialog(Context theContext){
    my= new Dialog(theContext);
}
public void showRobozoxDialog(){
    my.show();
}
public void setSource(String title,String url) {

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_dialog);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url); 
    my.setTitle(title);
}
}
```

Custom Dialog XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview_dialog"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</WebView>
```

Calling Dialog Like this.

```
RobozoxDialog d = new RobozoxDialog(MainActivity.this);
d.setSource("Test", "file:///android_asset/test.html");
d.showRobozoxDialog();
```

But getting error and unable to solve the problem. When i show html file in webview of main activity xml it is showing. but when try to show in dialog webview it stops working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done this by using LayoutInflater Code is below..

```
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(theContext);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            theContext);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Registration");

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final WebView webview = (WebView) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.webview_dialog);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Always add the logcat output to your question. We don't know what error you are getting.
2. You never set any layout to your Dialog. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) how to create a custom Dialog.
3. You try to get the WebView from the Activity instead of the Dialog. Try `my.findViewById(R.id.webview_dialog)`